# Using DISTINCT on Mysql IN operator

Tags: mysql

I want to know how i can do something like this:

```
select * from mytable
where id in distinct('11','12','11','13');
```

Ive never seen anyone use `distinct` on a `in` list before so wanted to know if the in list is already by default distinct?

Comment: yes it is distinct. '11' is in ('11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11'). First one it gets to, it's happy

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `in distinct ()`. The `in` operator yields true if the value is in the list, false otherwise. There is no difference between `'11' in distinct('11','12','11','13')` and `'11' in distinct('11','12','13')`, both result in `true`.